# Generate probability function to determine values of individuals based on discrete CDF function

Tags: probability, python

The below figure reports a logarithmic cumulative distribution function of time durations in
seconds. 68.14% of these durations lasted less than one minute, 96.28% for less than one hour, and 99.82% for less than one day.

[image]

How can I create a probability distribution function using this graph of CDF values? I want to use that function in my simulation to determine the duration of individual nodes based on the probability distribution function.

Comment: What do you mean by "probability distribution function"?  Do you mean density function? Or do you want to simulate values (in which case you can transpose that graph or resample from your original data)?

Comment: I am creating a simulation network and need to assign a "duration" value to each node based on this CDF function (from other research). Not sure what's the best way to do it. Sorry for being unclear, I lack expertise in this area.

Comment: So generate a uniform random variable in $[0,1]$ and find the largest time that gives that corresponds to that cumulative probability or less.  For example, if you generated $0.1$ then you want $1$ second, if you generated $0.2$ then you want $2$ seconds,  if you generated $0.4$ then you want $6$ seconds, if you generated $0.8$ then about $200$ seconds (if I read the graph correctly)